# Zend framework: using BreadCrumbs with partial

Tags: zend-framework, breadcrumbs

I have some trouble making a customized breadcrumb:
I my layout.phtml I have:

```
$container = new Zend_Navigation();
$this->navigation($container);

$container->addPage(
array(
    'label'      => 'Dashboard',
    'module'     => 'default',
    'controller' => 'dashboard',
    'action'     => 'index',
    'pages'      =>
    array(
        array(
            'label'      => 'Create Order',
            'module'     => 'default',
            'controller' => 'createorder',
            'action'     => 'index'
        ),
        array(
            'label'      => 'Query',
            'module'     => 'default',
            'controller' => 'query',
            'action'     => 'index',
            'pages' => array(
                array(
                    'label'      => 'View Order',
                    'module'     => 'default',
                    'controller' => 'order',
                    'action'     => 'vieworder'
                )
            )
        ),
        array(
            'label'      => 'Administration',
            'module'     => 'default',
            'controller' => 'admin',
            'action'     => 'index',
            'pages'      =>
            array(
                array(
                    'label'      => 'News and Announcements',
                    'module'     => 'default',
                    'controller' => 'admin',
                    'action' => 'addnews',
                    'pages' => array(
                        array(
                            'label'      => 'Edit News and Announcements',
                            'module'     => 'default',
                            'controller' => 'admin',
                            'action' => 'editnews'
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
);
```

The next line is:

```
echo $this->navigation()->breadcrumbs()->setPartial(array('BreadCrumb.phtml','default'));
```

The BreadCrumb.phtml is called well, but I don't know how to make an ul-li menu in my BreadCrumb.phtml. How do I get the navigation I'm actually in?
Thanks in advance for any help. Andrea

Answer (score 4):

To do so, your BreadCrumb.phtml should look like this:

```
<?php
if (null === $this->container) {
    $this->container = $this->breadcrumbs()->getContainer();
}

// find deepest active
if (!$active = $this->breadcrumbs()->findActive($this->container)) {
    return '';
}

$active = $active['page'];

// put the deepest active page last in breadcrumbs
if ($this->breadcrumbs()->getLinkLast()) {
    $html = ' <li>' . $this->breadcrumbs()->htmlify($active) . '</li>' . PHP_EOL;
} else {
    $html = $active->getLabel();
    if ($this->breadcrumbs()->getUseTranslator() && $t = $this->breadcrumbs()->getTranslator()) {
        $html = $t->translate($html);
    }
    $html = ' <li>' . $this->escape($html) . '</li>' . PHP_EOL;
}

// walk back to root
while (($parent = $active->getParent()) != null) {
    if ($parent instanceof Zend_Navigation_Page) {
        // prepend crumb to html
        $html = ' <li>' . $this->breadcrumbs()->htmlify($parent) . '</li>' . PHP_EOL . $html;
    }

    if ($parent === $this->container) {
        // at the root of the given container
        break;
    }

    $active = $parent;
}
echo strlen($html) ? $this->breadcrumbs()->getIndent() . '<ul id="breadcrumbs">' . PHP_EOL 
                 . $html .  '</ul>' . PHP_EOL : '';
?>
```

Then you will get something like this:

```
<ul id="breadcrumbs">
    <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/articles">Articles</a></li>
    <li><a href="/shop">Shop</a></li>
    <li>Last link</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No problem, I improved a little bit my code to make it work even if there is nothing to render. Let me know!

Comment: This is a godd example of rendering the breadcrumbs, @Liyali ! Where did you find it? This one should be added to the official docs example - the current one is "poor": http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.navigation.view.helper.breadcrumbs.html#rendering-using-a-partial-view-script

Comment: @Liyali Where did you find the code used in your example?

Comment: ooops zf1! Thought it's for zf2. Didn't pay attention to the tags

Answer (score 0):

Inside the view script, the zend navigation container is retrievable via `$this->container`. The container is iterable, so you can walk through it with a simple foreach loop (e.g. `foreach($this->container as $page)`

Answer (score 0):

I've found simple solution for render breadcrumbs wrapped in ul-li menu.

You can place this code in your *breadcrumbs.phtml*:

```
<?php $breadcrumbs = $this->navigation()->breadcrumbs()->setMinDepth(0); ?>
<?php $items = array_filter(explode($breadcrumbs->getSeparator(), $breadcrumbs->render())); ?>
<?php if ($items) : ?>
    <ul class="breadcrumbs">
        <?php foreach ($items as $item) : ?>
            <li><?= $item ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```